# Display likers username in html template

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have added a user liking system, where a user can like posts. I have added this successfully, however can't seem to display the usernames of the people who liked the post. This is my current implementation.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

views.py

```
def likepost(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            post.is_liked = True
            post.likes.remove(user)
            post.save()
        else:
            post.is_liked = False
            post.likes.add(user)
            post.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

home.html

```
 {% for post in posts.all %}
        <form id="like__post" method="POST" action="{% url 'likepost' post.id %}">
                {% csrf_token%}
                <input type="hidden">
              </form>
              <div style="position: absolute; bottom:80px; left: 85px;">
              {% if post.is_liked == True %}
                      <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post').submit()}"><img src="{% static 'heartred.png' %}" width="35px" height="35px"></a>
              {% else %}
                      <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post').submit()}"><img src="{% static 'heart.png' %}" width="33px" height="33px"></a>
              {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

 <ul> {{ post.likes }} </ul>
```

So far. In my template i get this:   **auth.User.None**

Comment: You don't seem to have shown the template that is having the problem.

Comment: Oh my bad I cut it out accidentally. Take a look at the html template again

Answer (score 0):

`likes` is a many to many field, you need to iterate over it.

```
<ul>
{% for like in post.likes.all %}
 <li>{{ like.username }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey I add this to my code and get an error.  (ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable)

Comment: Hey, I have added this to my code, however this time nothing at all appears on the page.

Comment: I have also added   .all(), however get this error: (Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'post.likes.all()').

Comment: I don't think the iteration bit it working because I removed the body of the for, and replaced it with a <p> tag It still didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have any likes for that post?